# string.template with arrays as placeholders

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I have a string that I'm trying to format that looks like this:

```
output = """<div class="form-group" id="$info["id"]_container">"""
```

The formatting call looks like this:

```
Template(output).substitute(locals())
```

My problem is that the substitution is working, but it's substituting all of the values of the info array instead of the id value that I want.

Here's the output:

```
<div class="form-group" id="{'name': 'my_name', 'type': 'my_type', 'label': 'my_label', 'help_text': 'my_help_text', 'id': 'my_id', 'placeholder': 'my_placeholder', 'class': 'my_class'}["id"]_container">
```

Here's the output that I want:

```
<div class="form-group" id="my_id_container">
```

I've tried using `{$info["id"]}`, and it just treats it as part of the string and there's no substitution.  I've also tried `${$info["id"]}`, and it gives:

```
ValueError: Invalid placeholder in string: line 1, col 51
```

I would really like to accomplish this without using the `%s` syntax. Is this possible?

For reference, here's all of the code:

```
   info = {
        "type" : "my_type",
        "name" : "my_name",
        "id" : "my_id",
        "class" : "my_class",
        "label" : "my_label",
        "placeholder" : "my_placeholder",
        "help_text" : "my_help_text"
    }

        output = """<div class="form-group" id="$info["id"]_container">"""
        output_sub = Template(output).substitute(locals())
```

Comment: do you have a dict called info in your code or where exactly is info declared in your code?

Comment: you have a dict called info what else do you expect? you are replacing $info with that dict that is stored in locals

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well, I'm expecting $info["id"] to be replaced with the value that is in that dict location.  Instead, it's replacing $info with the value of the whole array

Comment: can you add a desire output?

Comment: locals holds all your local variable so `$info` will be replaced by whatever the value for info is, try `print(locals()["info"])`

Comment: @Kasra Added desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the new [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) string formatting syntax:

```
output = """<div class="form-group" id="{info_id}_container">""".format(info_id=info['id'])
```

or even:

```
info = {'id': 'my_id'}
output = """<div class="form-group" id="{id}_container">""".format(**info)
```

Comment: I might have to do go that way, but the problem is the strings are going to be fairly large with lots of substitutions, and the locals() trick is saving me a lot of typing

Comment: @JeremyT: I'm not sure why that means my answer is wrong; all variables should be collected into a dictionary which can then be expanded using `**`. Using `locals()` is, as you said, a trick, it's not exactly the right way to do things as you've then tied your local variable names to the contents of your template string (which should remain unrelated).

Comment: To be clear, I didn't give you the downvote. And after looking it over again, I think your second suggestion might do the trick.

Comment: @JeremyT: cool! Looking at the code you've added, it seems you already have everything in a `info` variable. So if you leave out `info` from the template string then you can specify everything using the keys of that `info` dictionary.

Comment: fyi, the **info worked, but I had to use the ${id} placeholder for it to work. {} just comes through as part of the string

Answer (score 1):

You have a dict called `info` in your code so you are replacing `$info` with that because the value of the key `info` in `locals()` is that  dict, if you want to use the values in info just use the info dict:

Use:

```
 print(string.Template(output).substitute(**info))
<div class="form-group" id="id["id"]_container">
```

Or:

```
output = """<div class="form-group" id="$id["id"]_container">"""
print(string.Template(output).substitute(info))



In [3]: info = {'name': 'name', 'type': 'type', 'label': 'label', 'help_text': 'help_text', 'id': 'id', 'placeholder': 'placeholder', 'class': 'class'}

In [4]: locals()["info"] # what your code is accessing
Out[4]: 
{'class': 'class',
 'help_text': 'help_text',
 'id': 'id',
 'label': 'label',
 'name': 'name',
 'placeholder': 'placeholder',
 'type': 'type'}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you. This just seems to be a downvote type day.

Comment: no worries, locals holds all the local variables so you are getting the whole dict as a value using the key `info` in locals.

Answer (score 1):

As keyword in `Template` can't be an expression you can't use a keyword like `info["id"]` :
if you want to use `Template` you need an output like :

`output = """<div class="form-group" id="${info}_container">"""`

But in other way you can use `format` or `%s` .

```
>>> output = """<div class="form-group" id="${info}_container">"""
>>> print string.Template(output).substitute(info=info["id"])
<div class="form-group" id="id_container">
```

Comment: Solution works, but I much prefer the **info syntax because it saves me a great deal of typing